# Command works in Terminal but not via C system()

Tags: c, macos, zsh

I am using a Mac Catalina and am trying to use a function installed by homebrew.This problem has been a particularly puzzling one for me. I have tried to call this command a variety of ways. It functions on the shells zsh and bash, and I know that regular commands not added by homebrew work fine in the shell, but they don't when made with the C system() call. I have tried to make the same call in python, which says that it's os.system() is implemented using the C system() call, but it works in python. Both C and the terminal are using the same shell (zsh), but when C attempts the says that the command isn't found. Why can python and the terminal find the command installed by homebrew but not C? I'll post the C code if that helps.

This is what the C returns: sh: 7z: command not found
But echo $SHELL with C returns bin/zsh, just like the terminal.
I also did try the sh shell, but doing it 7z in that shell worked as well. The last thing I tried was C calling python and python calling os.system, but that led to the same command not found response, even though python's os.system() worked when attempted from the terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main() { 
system("7z e /Users/...something.7z -p abc"); 
}
```

Comment: `echo $SHELL` shows your login shell and not your currently running shell. You can use `ps -p $$; true` instead to get some idea, though it likely unrelated to the problem. What does `type 7z` say in your terminal?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the path used by the shell that `system()` uses to run the command.  Homebrew installs programs in a directory belonging to it, right, not in the default system directories?

Comment: Perhaps Homebrew is adding its directories to an initialization file (say, .bashrc) that is only read by login shells.

Comment: Note, too, that there is not necessarily any inconsistency between the messaging you obtain via the `system()` function.  A conforming implementation of that function will execute the given command via `/bin/sh`, but on Catalina, `/bin/sh` is `zsh` (and on Linux, it's typically `bash`).

Comment: I have macOS Catalina, homebrew, and 7z installed and could not duplicate the problem.

Comment: Do you remember how you installed 7z? I did it through p7zip.

Comment: I installed p7zip via brew.

Comment: I did it the same way. Using ps -p $$; true, the terminal is using zsh, but c is using sh.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` gives me `/bin/bash` because I never switched.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out: I was compiling and running C in Jgrasp. When I took the C and ran it in the terminal, it worked.